# Hierarchy missing, how do I bring it back?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a model in Blender and then I think I pressed something on my keyboard and then my hierarchy went missing! How can I bring it back again?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you hide part of your mesh?  The user interface .. search for Hide .. Unhide .. variations of the letter H

Comment: Click on the top menu button beside help (Back previous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've maximized a viewport.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should set it back.

Comment: Yes thank you! I have it back now.